# Nginx - how to return a proxy generated file?

Tags: http, rest, nginx, reverse-proxy

**Description:**

I want to implement an http server (using nginx) that serves static files.

If the requested file doesn't exist, nginx shall send a request to a service (REST API) that will create the file and return its path.

After that, I want nginx to return the static file that was created.

**Question:**

What is the best way to return the file after its creation?

So far I managed to do this by changing the REST API in order to return the created file path with the 302 status code and with a location header as a redirect, but I am not sure if this is a good thing to do. Is it?

Is there any nginx-side solution for this? Do I have to create a custom module?

**Conf file:**

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /files {
            try_files $uri @rest;
        }

        location @rest {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/ break;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want is actually a cache in front of your REST API, which is something that ngx_http_proxy_module can already handle on its own...

Comment: @DaveRandom I am not sure if cache is the answer. Once the file is created it should be available as static content for the following requests (served directly by nginx). Cache can only provide temporary content, right?

Comment: If you set the headers in your REST API such that the file will be cached for 10 years, then the file will effectively be served statically by Nginx for 10 years. It depends what your goal is here - if you just want to avoid doing expensive tasks in your API more than once, then all you really need is a cache. If you actually specifically want the files to exist (say, because some other local process needs them) then I would imagine the only thing you could do would be to create a custom module. The solution below isn't ideal because you'd need to adjust the REST API response.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Actually, on balance, this should be even simpler:

```
location @rest {
    ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page     404 = $uri;
}
```

Configure the named location to intercept an "error" coming back (I chose 404), and then using the `error_page` directive will cause the given URI to be loaded again.  Since the file now exists, the request should succeed.

Side note: I had thought `try_files $uri @rest $uri` would have worked, but an internal redirection only happens for the last argument.

---

The simplest option here is probably for your REST service to use `X-Sendfile`/`X-Accel` to return the relevant URI that Nginx should serve once the file is created.  Your REST service could return the target URI using the header `X-Accel-Redirect`.

In your case, your API could actually just return the same URI it received as the `X-Accel-Redirect` header, and then Nginx would re-use the same location block and find the file for the subrequest occurring.

If this fails, however, using an internal Nginx location as per the examples at http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile and http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel:

```
location /files-protected {
    internal;
    root /path/to/files;
}
```

and returning the relevant URI to that would also work.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work but I am wondering if there is a NGINX side solution. I'm skeptical about changing response headers because it seems to me that by doing so I am creating a dependency, since I am using the REST API to send nginx headers, right?

Comment: Check out the updated edit above.  Intercepting an error from your REST API and configuring an ``error_page`` will enable to you to perform another attempt at accessing the newly-created file.